# how to declare NSOrderedDecending

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
static NSInteger shakeCount=0;
static NSDate *shakeStart;
static NSOrderedDecending;

NSDate *now=[[NSDate alloc]init];
NSDate *checkDate=[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:1.5f sinceDate:shakeStart];
if([now compare:checkDate]==NSOrderedDecending || shakeStart ==nil)
{
    shakeCount=0;
    [shakeStart release];
    shakeStart=[[NSDate alloc]init];
}
[now release];
[checkDate release];


if(fabsf(acceleration.x) > 2.0
    || fabsf(acceleration.y) > 2.0      
    || fabsf(acceleration.z) > 2.0)
{
    shakeCount++;
    if(shakeCount>4)
    {

        shakeCount=0;
        [shakeStart release];
        shakeStart =[[NSDate alloc]init];
    }
}
}
```

But getting error as "NSOrderedDecending not declare".

Answer (score 2):

It's `NSOrderedDescending`, not `NSOrderedDecending`. Note de**SC**end vs. de**C**end

Comment: And remove the `static NSOrderedDecending;` "statement" too.